# Help constructing a class with ArrayList as a parameter

Tags: java, arraylist

Ive been trying to work this out for a few hours now, but am stuck, hence I am coming here for some help.
N.B. I am using BlueJ, to construct these classes, as im still learning.

What I am trying to do is create a PlayList which has a two parameters: name and a ArrayList of tracks. 
It then creates a playlist and copies the tracks from the list (in order) onto the playlist; but I dont want any help with this part, as of yet.

My issue is I am unsure how to call the ArrayList when constructing the PlayList.. Because the specified type is of .

```
public class PlayList
{    
private String myName;
private ArrayList<Track> myTracks;
private int myDuration;

public PlayList(String name, ArrayList<Track> tracks) {
    name = myName;
    myTracks = new ArrayList<Track>();
    for (Track t : tracks) {
        myTracks.add(t);
    }
}
```

}

What happens, in BlueJ, is when I construct a new PlayList class, it provides an empty field box for String name, and for ArrayList tracks. String name is fine, as I can simply put "anything" but am stuck as to the ArrayList tracks?

I know this is probably isnt a very specific question, but I am still learning.

Comment: Are you asking us how to design the GUI so that the user can enter the data for some number of Track objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of your `PlayList` wants an object of type `ArrayList` filled with elements of type `Track`. So to create a PlayList you must provide an already created one.

It depends on your surrounding of the call, maybe you already build a list there and can just put it into your PlayList constructor, but you need something like this anywhere:

```
// Create an empty list
ArrayList<Track> tracks = new ArrayList<Track>();
// Add a track. e.g. when receiving a gui event
tracks.add(track); // track was created with new Track()
```

Or maybe you don't need/want lists outside of `PlayList` objects. You could use `PlayList` objects to manage and encapsulate those, by changing the constructor to only create an empty list on its own and allow others to add tracks to it via an `addTrack` method.

Answer (score 2):

sunadorer's response should answer your direct question. I have some general remarks about naming conventions for the fields in your class and the parameters of your constructor.

I would not prefix your fields with 'my'. It is a bit of a matter of style, but I would not have much against using the same names for the constructor parameters. You can distinguish between the parameter and the field by using `this.name` when referring to the field.

Also, using `ArrayList` here seems unnecessarily restrictive: you could use the more general `List` interface (which `ArrayList` is just one implementation of, so you don't have to touch `PlayList` if you want another kind of `List` later o):

```
public class PlayList {    

  private String name;
  private List<Track> tracks;
  private int duration;

  public PlayList(String name, List<Track> tracks) {
    this.name = name;
    this.tracks = new ArrayList<Track>(tracks);
  }
}
```

Comment: You should add the type parameters to the `List tracks` again, without them it's worst than having `ArrayList` in your constructor signature IMHO.

Comment: +1 for suggesting List instead of ArrayList. Just to go a bit further, will it be better to have List<Track>?

Comment: He Should NOT use `List` if he knows what type of List it is, maybe `List<Track>`. this is also more appropriate as a comment then an answer.

Comment: Might also want to use the [copy-constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection)) of `ArrayList` to save the whole loop-and-add thing: `new ArrayList<Track>(tracks);`

Comment: Just looked at the source of @Arnout's answer and the type paramters are already **in there**, he just used `<code><pre>` tags instead of the 4-spaces-indentation so SO filtered out the `<Track>` as HTML. I edited his answer and it's pending review.

Comment: @Arnout: If you want to write longer code blocks and don't like indenting every single line with 4 spaces (no one does \*g\*), just select your code block and then click the `{ }` icon in the editor's tool bar -- it will auto-indent your code block.

Comment: @amit sorry, SO ate my generics ;). I considered making this a comment, but you can't have multi-line formatted code blocks in comments, can you?